# Assigning default value to a column using XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a simple query... What am trying to accomplish here is to display 'name' variable value in all the rows in "Developed by" column. Here is my below xml and xslt. Could anyone tell me what is the xslt expression which I need to use to pull variable value and place it in all rows, something like .

Thanks.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS Records</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Greatest Hits</title>
            <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>RCA</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1982</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Still got the blues</title>
            <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Virgin records</company>
            <price>10.20</price>
            <year>1990</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Eros</title>
            <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
            <country>EU</country>
            <company>BMG</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1997</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>One night only</title>
            <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Polydor</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1998</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
            <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS</company>
            <price>8.10</price>
            <year>1973</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Maggie May</title>
            <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Pickwick</company>
            <price>8.50</price>
            <year>1990</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Romanza</title>
            <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
            <country>EU</country>
            <company>Polydor</company>
            <price>10.80</price>
            <year>1996</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
            <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Atlantic</company>
            <price>8.70</price>
            <year>1987</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Black angel</title>
            <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
            <country>EU</country>
            <company>Mega</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1995</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
            <artist>Many</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Grammy</company>
            <price>10.20</price>
            <year>1999</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>For the good times</title>
            <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Mucik Master</company>
            <price>8.70</price>
            <year>1995</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Big Willie style</title>
            <artist>Will Smith</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1997</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
            <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Polydor</company>
            <price>8.20</price>
            <year>1971</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Soulsville</title>
            <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
            <country>Norway</country>
            <company>WEA</company>
            <price>7.90</price>
            <year>1996</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>The very best of</title>
            <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Island</company>
            <price>8.90</price>
            <year>1990</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Stop</title>
            <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>A and M</company>
            <price>8.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
            <artist>T`Pau</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Siren</company>
            <price>7.90</price>
            <year>1987</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Private Dancer</title>
            <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Capitol</company>
            <price>8.90</price>
            <year>1983</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Midt om natten</title>
            <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
            <country>EU</country>
            <company>Medley</company>
            <price>7.80</price>
            <year>1983</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
            <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>DECCA</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1991</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>The dock of the bay</title>
            <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Atlantic</company>
            <price>7.90</price>
            <year>1987</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Picture book</title>
            <artist>Simply Red</artist>
            <country>EU</country>
            <company>Elektra</company>
            <price>7.20</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Red</title>
            <artist>The Communards</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>London</company>
            <price>7.80</price>
            <year>1987</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Unchain my heart</title>
            <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>EMI</company>
            <price>8.20</price>
            <year>1987</year>
        </cd>
    </catalog>









        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="name" value="NAV"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
          <th>Developed by</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
```

with this:

```
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="{$name}"/></td>
    </tr>
```